# Determine the bond angle in a compound

Tags: bond, hybridization, valence-bond-theory, molecular-structure

How can we find the bond angle between 3 atoms in a compound?
Please specify an equation which can be used for all compounds.

Comment: There is no such equation. The bond angle can be estimated by some simple rules, such as [VSEPR theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSEPR_theory).

Comment: If you know atomic coordinates (say, from a single-crystal diffraction experiment), then the task is basically the same as finding an angle between two vectors in 3D space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In carbon compounds Coulson's Theorem can be used to relate bond angles to the hybridization indices of the bonds involved.

$$1+\lambda_{i} \lambda_{j} \cos(\theta_{ij})=0$$

where $\ce{\lambda_{i}}$ represents the hybridization index of the $\ce{C-i}$ bond (the hybridization index is the square root of the bond hybridization) and $\ce{\theta_{ij}}$ represents the $\ce{i-C-j}$ bond angle.

[image]

Let's look at some examples.

- In the case of methane, each $\ce{C-H}$ bond is $\ce{sp^3}$ hybridized and the hybridization index of each $\ce{C-H}$ bond is $\sqrt3$. Using Coulson's theorem we find that the $\ce{H-C-H}$ bond angle is 109.5 degrees.
- In the case of the methyl carbocation ($\ce{CH3^{+}}$) the $\ce{C-H}$ bonds are $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridized and the hybridization index of each $\ce{C-H}$ bond is $\sqrt2$.  In this case, using Coulson's theorem we find that the $\ce{H-C-H}$ bond angle is 120 degrees.
- Finally, in the case of acetylene the $\ce{C-H}$ bond is $\ce{sp}$ hybridized and the hybridization index of each $\ce{C-H}$ bond is $\sqrt1$.  In this case, using Coulson's theorem we find that the $\ce{C-C-H}$ bond angle is 180 degrees.

Conversely, if the bond angle is known, the hybridization can be determined.