# Inductive effect and bond strength

Tags: organic-chemistry, valence-bond-theory

What is the relation between the inductive effect on bond length and strength.

how would one rank the bond strength of

$\ce{CH3-H}$, $\ce{CH3CH2-H}$, and $\ce{(CH3)2CH-H}$

I know that alkyl groups donate electron density by induction, but how does electron density in a bond affect its length or strength?

Answer (score 1):

Just as hyperconjugation stabilizes carbocations and radicals by sharing the electron density of adjacent $\ce{C-H}$ bonds with the unoccupied/partially occupied orbital, hyperconjugation destabilizes carbanions. So more substitution means less acidic and more ionizable. I had a hard time finding a single resource listing bond lengths, but they seem to correlate with bond-dissociation energy. The [wikipedia page for methane](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methane) states that its $\ce{C-H}$ bond length is 108.7 pm and [an answer by Jan](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/52123/15410) says ethane’s is 109.4 pm.

$$ \small
\begin{array}{lcc}
\hline
\text{Hydrocarbon} & \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} ^{[1]} & \text{BDE (kcal)}^{[2]}\\
\hline
\ce{CH3-H} & 48 & 104\\
\ce{CH3CH2-H} & - & 98\\
\ce{(CH3)2CH-H} & 51 &  95\\
\ce{(CH3)3C-H} & 53 & 93\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

---

<sup>$[1]$  [Evan’s pKa Table](http://evans.rc.fas.harvard.edu/pdf/evans_pKa_table.pdf)

$[2]$ [Wikipedia: Carbon-Hydrogen Bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon%E2%80%93hydrogen_bond)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

–I effect increase the bond strength and force constant, increase of bond strength is possible only by holding two atoms closer than earlier. hence -I effect reduces bond length and increases bond strength

Answer (score -3):

since the inductive effect leads to ionic character in the bond,the increase in -I effect decreases the bond length.