# Which is more stable? A phenyl carbanion or a disubstituted vinylic carbanion?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability

I came across a question which asks to work out the stability order for the following species-

> b. [image: benzene carbanion]
>
> c. $\ce{R2C=CH-}$

Can the lone pair on phenyl carbanion participate in resonance?  If yes, then how? Also, how is that more stable than the vinylic carbanion?

Comment: No it doesn't participate in resonance.

Comment: Then how come it is more stable than the primary vinylic carbanion ?

Comment: Again... stable towards what exactly? I find these (I suppose exam) question rather weird asking about stability of compounds without a proper context.

Comment: @Jori, unfortunately these questions are a lot to come by, at least here. Hmm, I put them like this: The compound that is more stable produces lesser heat upon decomposition.

Comment: @MARamezani What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Also, why close this question? It is not homework. I think OP could have tried to add some more of his own thought, but I consider it on-topic. If we do not want to scare too many newcomers away I think we should not have a too harsh policy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The lone pair on the benzene is in the plane of the ring and hence orthogonal to the conjugated $\pi$-system so that it cannot interact with it. It is $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridized just like the vinylic carbanion, which also cannot resonate. Furthermore, both compounds lack an electron withdrawing group, so there is no inductive effect either. [Looking at the pKa values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbanion) for both compounds, which usually gives a good indication about the stability of the anion, we see that there is indeed hardly any difference between them (pKa of benzene ~43 vs pKa of propene ~44 vs [pKa of ethylene](http://bama.ua.edu/~kshaughn/ch531/531-handouts/pKa-values.pdf) ~44).

In your question you only show us option (b) and (c). It would be nice if you could show the whole question including all possibilities (also as much as possible in text please, so the search engines can find it!)

Comment: I got the order partially right. So I did not the whole question.

Comment: Jori, there are basically two different types of protons in propene; those attached to an $\ce{sp^2}$ carbon and those attached to an $\ce{sp^3}$ carbon. Which type of proton in propene is responsible for the pKa you reported?

Comment: @ron I assumed it would be for the $\ce{sp^2}$ since I suspected that the $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridization was of more importance than the allylic conjugation. Comparison with the pKa of 3,3-Dimethyl-1-butene would give a more definite answer for sure, but I cannot find it anywhere. However comparing with the pKa of ethylene, which is also ~44, gives a good hint in this direction. I simply listed that table because it listed both types of compounds at the same place.

Comment: @Jori, I didnt umderstand the reason why it is not participating in resonance. Its SP2 hy ridized in benzene ring and also planar molucule. Which part of the rule does it exactly violate. Please, enlighten me a bit on this

Comment: In the deprotonated vinylic molecule, the lone pair is *not* in an sp2 hybridised orbital. As soon as the proton is detached (or even while it is detached) the hydrogen will not uphold the $120^\circ$ $\angle\ce{CCH}$, but adapts a linear geometry with $180^\circ$. The carbon itself is then sp hybridised and the lone pair is in a p orbital perpendicular to the $\pi$ bond.

Comment: @Martin That is interesting. I suppose that is part of more advanced molecular orbital theory, which is sadly badly treated by most undergraduate organic chemistry books. I think Clayden does a better job than most other books, but still maintains a relatively simple model of hybridization. To what extend does that change the answer to the question? You make it sound like it is that then the benzene anion, which cannot lock the lone pair away in a p-orbital I assume, would be more stable then, yet the pKa seems pretty constant at ~44.

Comment: The model of hybridisation is fine, but one must always keep in mind, that breaking bonds will result in a different geometry and therefore also hybridisation changes. Your point is valid though, both of the molecules should be about equally stable (read: they are both quite reactive towards electrophiles) and you did of course draw that conclusion from experimental measurements. From MO I would assume the ethylene derivate being a bit more stable due to hyperconjugation which cannot be present in the benzyl anion.

Comment: @Martin You commented that the vinyl carbanion will adopt a linear configuration.  That may be true for a vinyl cation, but is it also true for the vinyl carbanion? I would have thought that the carbanion would  be bent with a barrier to inversion (just like an imine).  The lone pair would be more stable in an sp2 orbital rather than a p orbital.  Hybridization is a way to answer the OP's question.  The C-H bond in benzene is $\ce{sp^2}$ while the C-H bond in ethylene is $\ce{sp^{2.2}}$, consequently the phenyl carbanion is more stable.  If this question is reopened I will write more.

Comment: I was wrong about the geometry, see [*J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1978**, *100* (19), pp 6007–6012](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00487a005). The lone pair is still not sp2 though. I think hybridisation is a poor concept to explain stability in any case (as long as we are not talking about highly accurate VB theory calculations and even then it is a stretch). I am tired of talking about hybridisation though. (If you want this question to be reopened, you have to rework it yourself I fear.)

Answer (score 17):

> Can the lone pair on benzene carbanion participate in resonance?

As Jori has pointed out, the carbanion lone pair is orthogonal to the pi system of the aromatic ring.  Therefore it cannot participate in resonance.  Here is a drawing that illustrates this point.

[image: Structure of benzene anion]

> how is it more stable than vinylic carbanion?

The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ approach discussed in @Jori's answer becomes problematic when we are trying to look at a small difference between two large $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$s.  A $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $43$ means $1$ ionized molecule exists in every $10^{43}$ molecules.  Certainly difficult to measure experimentally and so a significant error is attached to these estimates. In fact, using the data from [Evan's $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ table](http://evans.harvard.edu/pdf/evans_pKa_table.pdf) we find a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $43$ for the benzene $\ce{C-H}$ proton and a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $50$ for an ethylenic proton, suggesting that the phenyl carbanion might be more stable than the vinyl carbanion.

**An alternate way** to examine this question involves comparing the hybridizations of the phenyl and ethylenic $\ce{C-H}$ bonds.  Since bonds with more $\mathrm{s}$-character will stabilize electrons better than bonds with less $\mathrm{s}$-character (because the $\mathrm{s}$-orbital is lower energy than a $\mathrm{p}$-orbital), whichever bond has more $\mathrm{s}$-character should produce a more stable carbanion.

The $\ce{C-H}$ bond in benzene is exactly $\mathrm{sp^2}$ hybridized as required by the symmetry of the benzene molecule.  Experimentally, we know that the $\ce{H-C-H}$ angle in ethylene is $117^\circ$.  Using this fact along with Coulson's theorem ([reference1](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22267/whats-the-h-c-h-bond-angle-in-ethene/22278#22278), [reference2](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19977/determine-the-bond-angle-in-a-compound/19987#19987), [reference3](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19977/determine-the-bond-angle-in-a-compound/19987#19987)) we can determine that the $\ce{C-H}$ bond in ethylene is $\mathrm{sp}^{2.2}$  hybridized.

The $\mathrm{sp^2}$ hybridized orbital in benzene has more s-character than the $\mathrm{sp}^{2.2}$ hybridized orbital in ethylene.  This would lead us to suspect that **the phenyl carbanion is more stable than the vinyl carbanion**.

Of course, once we remove these protons we expect the resulting carbanions to undergo further rehybridization in order to further stabilize their lone pair (carbanion) electrons.  It seems like a reasonable first approximation that they would both rehybridize similar amounts and the "relaxed" phenyl carbanion would remain more stable than the "relaxed" vinyl carbanion.  But in any case, the transition state leading to the phenyl carbanion will be more stable than the transition state leading to the vinyl carbanion because of the hybridization \ $\mathrm{s}$-character reasons presented above.

**Edit:** OP's comment on hybridization

Molecules are not just $\mathrm{sp, sp^{2}}$ or $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridized.  While the $\ce{C-H}$ bonds in methane are exactly $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridized (as required by symmetry), the $\ce{C-H}$ bonds in $\ce{CH3F}$ are not ([see here for a discussion](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/what-is-bents-rule/15622#15622)).  Bonds can have any hybridization index (the superscript to the right of "$\mathrm{p}$") between zero and infinity.  **Hybridization indices are not limited to integer values**, nature can mix $\mathrm{s}$ and $\mathrm{p}$ orbitals in whatever ratio is required to create the most stable bonds and molecules.

Comment: Cant we say that the vinylic one is more unstable due to electron releasing effect of R groups?

Comment: @Abcd Yes, if there are alkyl groups located near the carbanionic center then they could destabilize either carbanion inductively as you suggest.  However, I think this effect would be secondary to the hybridization effect discussed above,