# Which hydrogen of 3-methylcyclohex-2-en-1-one is the least acidic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, resonance

> Which hydrogen of 3-methylcyclohex-2-en-1-one is the least acidic?
>
> [image: 3-methylcyclohex-2-en-1-one]

**According to me it should be 2**, as on its removal there won't be any resonance stabilization as would happen in the other cases. In addition to that a negative charge residing on a carbon attached to a double bond would be highly unstable.
But the answer key says that it is 3.

**A follow up question:** Which is the most acidic hydrogen?

According to me it should be 4 as it leads to a greater number of resonance structures.

Comment: For your followup - how many resonance structures can you count for **4**? What about **1**?

Comment: Also, see http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26610/which-is-more-stable-a-carbanion-on-benzene-ring-or-a-carbanion-on-a-vinylic.

Comment: three resonating structures for 4  and two for 1

Comment: Did they ask something like "which of sp3 carbons have the least acidic hydrogen?" Or did they ask "which of these four hydrogens is the least acidic?" 2 indeed looks least acidic among all, because it is the only anion that doesn't have appropriate resonance structures.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You are correct. Position 2 is the least acidic.**

Position 3 is not the least acidic hydrogen. It might be the most acidic hydrogen. Position 2 is the least acidic hydrogen of the four marked.

What does position 2 have going for it? Why might it not have been marked as the least acidic? The lone pair that would be left in the conjugate base is sitting in a sp² orbital.

[image: 3-methylcyclohex-2-en-1-one deprotonation at position 2]

**All else equal**, sp² hybrid orbital containing $\ce{C-H}$ bonds are more acidic than sp³ hybrid orbital containing $\ce{C-H}$ bonds. The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of ethane $\ce{CH3CH3}$ is reported to be $\sim 50$, and the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of ethene $\ce{CH2=CH2}$ is reported to be $\sim 44$.

However, **all else is not equal**. Resonance, especially with a carbonyl group, stabilizes conjugate bases more. Acetone $\ce{CH2COCH3}$ has a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $\sim 19$. Position 2 is not stabilized by resonance. The conjugate bases from positions 1, 3, and 4 are all resonance stabilized through the carbonyl group.

Position 1 has two resonance structures.

[image: 3-methylcyclohex-2-en-1-one deprotonation at position 1]

Position 3 has three resonance structures.

[image: 3-methylcyclohex-2-en-1-one deprotonation at position 3]

Position 4 has three resonance structures.

[image: 3-methylcyclohex-2-en-1-one deprotonation at position 4]

It is between positions 3 and 4 for the most acidic. I chose position three because alkyl groups (the rest of the ring) are electron donating by induction, but alkyl group also stabilize pi bonds, so position 4 is a good candidate for most acidic as well.